# Getting user agent string of a Lync endpoint

Tags: lync, ucma, lync-2013

I'm building a routing application based on Lync 2013 using routing in `MSPL`, dispatching a requests to a `ServerAgent`, and handling calls with an UCMA Trusted Application with it's own `ApplicationEndpoint`.

Now I need to configure routing based on a user's active endpoints. Specifically, I need to find if a user has an endpoint which is a Lync Mobile (mobility) client.

I can get a list of the user's endpoints in the `MSPL` script, but this only gives the endpoint IDs, capabilities and it's GRUU. I will need the user agent string of each endpoint to be able to determine the apropriate routing.

Subscribing to a user's presence in `UCMA` can give me presence for the individual endpoints, but it will not get me the user agent strings either.

So far the only route I found is by accessing the Lync `.\rtclocal` SQL server and querying the `rtcdyn.dbo.RegistrarEndpoint` table. This would mean adding a SQL connection to each Frontend SQL server, which is a last-resort I would like to avoid at all costs.

What other options are there (preferably using `MSPL` or `UCMA`) to get all the user's endpoints including client version / useragent strings?

---

**Edit:**

- I have checked the MSPL compiler code, there is nothing that seems to get the user agent string for any endpoint except the current request. There are a few undocumented features but nothing that seems to help me.
- I checked if any of the enhanced presence containers has the information, but also found nothing.

---

**Edit 2:**

Some digging later, I think the best bet is to get the device type from the `"machineState"` presence category. Every endpoint publishes one of these, the XML is described on MSDN: [`state[@type='machineState'] element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454806%28v=office.15%29.aspx). It has a `device` element which can contain the following:

> **`computer`**: The device is a computer on which Lync 2013 is running.
>   **`deskphone`**: The device is a desk phone on which Lync Phone Edition is running.
>   **`mobile`**: The device is a mobile phone on which Microsoft Lync 2010 for Android, iPad, iPhone, Nokia, or Windows Phone is running.
>   **`web`**: This is a computer on which Microsoft Lync Web App is running.

But how to query this element from `MSPL`? There is the [`QueryCategory(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439174%28v=office.15%29.aspx) function, but this does not seem to return machine state, only the aggregate presense state.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can see it as a header in the SIP messages, I don't think you'll be able to get it from the MSPL script. (obviously, if you can see it as a header then you can query by it)

However, once you've dispatched the message, in the method that you dispatch to (that contains an `Object source` parameter, you can use

```
HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
HttpContext context = application.Context;
string userAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;
```

to get the userAgent string

Comment: All message headers are available in both MSPL and managed code, including the user agent. This is the user agent of the client which sent the current request, but I am looking for the user agents of the sender's other endpoints in order to decide routing.

Comment: can't you capture them all as they come in and keep in your own datastore for looking up when you need it? I don't think Lync will let you "query" anything for the user agents of other endpoints. But they'll all pass your MSPL at some point, so you can keep a track of them..